# texCoordPointer not working in lwjgl

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

I've been having problems storing texture coordinate points in a VBO, and then telling OpenGL to use it when it's time to render. In the code below, what I should be getting is a nice 16x16 texture on a square I am making using quads. However what I do get is the first top left pixel of the image instead which is red, so I get a big red square. Please tell me what I am doing wrong in great detail.

```
  public void start() {
    try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800,600));
        Display.create();
    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    // init OpenGL
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GL11.glOrtho(0, 800, 0, 600, 1, -1);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glLoadIdentity();

    //loadTextures();
    TextureManager.init();

    makeCube();

    // init OpenGL here

    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        // render OpenGL here
        renderCube();

        Display.update();
    }

    Display.destroy();
}

public static void main(String[] argv) {
    Screen screen = new Screen();
    screen.start();
}

int cube;
int texture;

private void makeCube() {
    FloatBuffer cubeBuffer;
    FloatBuffer textureBuffer;

    //Tried using 0,0,16,0,16,16,0,16 for textureData did not work.
    float[] textureData = new float[]{
            0,0,
            1,0,
            1,1,
            0,1};

        textureBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(textureData.length);
        textureBuffer.put(texture);
        textureBuffer.flip();

        texture = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texture);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        float[] cubeData = new float[]{
            /*Front Face*/
            100,       100,
            100 + 200, 100,
            100 + 200, 100 + 200,
            100,       100 + 200};

        cubeBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(cubeData.length);
        cubeBuffer.put(cubeData);
        cubeBuffer.flip();

        cube = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cube);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

}

private void renderCube(){
    TextureManager.texture.bind();

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texture);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cube);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is in the argument to `textureBuffer.put()` in this code fragment:

```
    textureBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(textureData.length);
    textureBuffer.put(texture);
    textureBuffer.flip();
```

`texture` is a variable of type `int`, which has not even been initialized yet. You later use it as a buffer name. The argument should be `textureData` instead:

```
    textureBuffer.put(textureData);
```

I normally try to focus on functionality over style when answering questions here, but I can't help it this time: IMHO, `texture` is a very unfortunate name for a buffer name. It's not only a style and readability question. If you used descriptive names for the variables, you most likely would have spotted this problem immediately.

Say you named the variable for the buffer name `bufferId` (I call object identifiers "id", even though the official OpenGL terminology is "name"), and the buffer holding the texture coordinates `textureCoordBuf`. The statement in question would then become:

```
textureCoordBuf.put(bufferId);
```

which would jump out as highly suspicious from even a very superficial look at the code.

Comment: Wow I feel so stupid haha. I guess everytime my brain scanned the word "texture" I thought it was my float array. I should probably name my variables better. Thank you very much sir! :D